# Apache CloudStack with MySQL Cluster (NDB Engine)

Tags: mysql, database-cluster, apache-cloudstack

I've recently set up a tested and verified MySQL Cluster 7.1 and tested and verified a 4.x version of CloudStack on a regular MySQL database. Now, I'm trying to move the DB to the new Cluster database. I exported and removed all of the constraints in the CloudStack databases and successfully imported the schema/data into the Cluster database. However, when I point CloudStack to the Cluster's IP address, it shows the login screen but when I try to log in, the CloudStack management server crashes. Has anyone successfully installed CloudStack on a MySQL Cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Capture the log file info when the mgmt server crashes.  [Info on CloudStack logs](http://dlafferty.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/using-cloudstacks-log-files-xenserver.html)

Post message to [CloudStack user mailing list](http://cloudstack.apache.org/mailing-lists.html).